# Find Files Recursively Of Size Range

Tags: find

Using the command line, how do I find all the files recursively beginning at a specific directory where all those files fall within a size range?

Additionally list the results sorted by size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
find /PATH/TO/specific_directory -size +MIN -size -MAX
```

For precise info about what `MIN` and `MAX` could be, check `man find`

> ```
>    -size n[cwbkMG]
>           File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
>           `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>
>           `c'    for bytes
>
>           `w'    for two-byte words
>
>           `k'    for kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)
>
>           `M'    for mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576 bytes)
>
>           `G'    for gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)
>
>           The size is simply the st_size member of the struct stat populated by the lstat (or stat) system call, rounded
>           up as shown above.  In other words, it's consistent with the result you get for ls -l.  Bear in mind that  the
>           `%k'  and  `%b'  format  specifiers of -printf handle sparse files differently.  The `b' suffix always denotes
>           512-byte blocks and never 1024-byte blocks, which is different to the behaviour of -ls.
>
>           The + and - prefixes signify greater than and less than, as usual; i.e., an exact size of  n  units  does  not
>           match.   Bear  in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit.  Therefore -size -1M is not equivalent to
>           -size -1048576c.  The former only matches empty files, the latter matches files from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.
> ```

---

*Update to meet your new requirements*:

```
find /PATH/TO/specific_directory -size +MIN -size -MAX -print0 | du --human-readable --files0-from=- | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

or, in its short form:

```
find /PATH/TO/specific_directory -size +MIN -size -MAX -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- | sort -h
```

*Update to meet your new requirements (2)*:

```
find /PATH/TO/specific_directory -size +MIN -size -MAX -print0 | du --human-readable --bytes --files0-from=- | sort
```

Comment: Is it possibe for the list to be sorted by size? I've updated the question because I did not specify that and I think that would be helpful.

Comment: yes: check my updated answer.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer but is it possible to see exact sizes vs. rounded sizes?

Comment: yes: If by 'exact sizes', you mean 'size in bytes', check my last update; If by 'exact sizes', you mean 'real size', check `man du`.

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` Files between 1K – 10M:

```
print -l /PATH/TO/DIR/**/*(.Lk+1Lm-10oL)
```

- Recursive glob: `**/*`
- For plain files: `(.)`
- > 1KiB: `(Lk+1)`
- but < 10MiB: `(Lm-10)`
- Sorted by size in ascending order: `(oL)`